# How to determine ARMv8 CPU's frequency?

Tags: linux, arm

I am running some basic testing in Ubuntu for ARMv8 (Linux-aarch64) with **QEMU emulator**.
I want to get current CPU's frequency (nominal frequency is preferred), but from the output of lscpu or cat /proc/cpuinfo, there is NO CPU frequency info.
The answers to a similar [question in stackexchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/589477/how-can-i-get-the-current-cpu-frequency-of-an-arm-processor-on-ubuntu) can NOT help me much.
The output of `perf stat sleep 1` is as follows,

```
 Performance counter stats for 'sleep 1':

         36.845824      task-clock (msec)         #    0.034 CPUs utilized
                 1      context-switches          #    0.027 K/sec
                 0      cpu-migrations            #    0.000 K/sec
                49      page-faults               #    0.001 M/sec
        36,759,401      cycles                    #    0.998 GHz
   <not supported>      instructions
   <not supported>      branches
   <not supported>      branch-misses

       1.068524527 seconds time elapsed
```

May I say the CPU is 1GHz?

The output of `cpupower` shows nothing about CPU frequency,

```
t@ubuntu:~/test/kermod$ sudo cpupower monitor
No HW Cstate monitors found

t@ubuntu:~/test/kermod$ sudo cpupower frequency-info
analyzing CPU 0:
  no or unknown cpufreq driver is active on this CPU
  CPUs which run at the same hardware frequency: Not Available
  CPUs which need to have their frequency coordinated by software: Not Available
  maximum transition latency:  Cannot determine or is not supported.
Not Available
  available cpufreq governors: Not Available
  Unable to determine current policy
  current CPU frequency: Unable to call hardware
  current CPU frequency:  Unable to call to kernel
t@ubuntu:~/test/kermod$ sudo cpupower info
System does not support Intel's performance bias setting
analyzing CPU 0:
```

The `dmidecode -t processor` shows,

```
t@ubuntu:~/test/kermod$ sudo dmidecode -t processor
# dmidecode 3.1
Getting SMBIOS data from sysfs.
SMBIOS 3.0.0 present.

Handle 0x0400, DMI type 4, 42 bytes
Processor Information
        Socket Designation: CPU 0
        Type: Central Processor
        Family: Other
        Manufacturer: QEMU
        ID: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
        Version: virt-4.2
        Voltage: Unknown
        External Clock: Unknown
        Max Speed: 2000 MHz
        Current Speed: 2000 MHz
        Status: Populated, Enabled
        Upgrade: Other
        L1 Cache Handle: Not Provided
        L2 Cache Handle: Not Provided
        L3 Cache Handle: Not Provided
        Serial Number: Not Specified
        Asset Tag: Not Specified
        Part Number: Not Specified
        Core Count: 1
        Core Enabled: 1
        Thread Count: 1
        Characteristics: None
```

It says the CPU is 2GHz, but I am not sure if that is correct.

Another way I can use is by sleeping for seconds and reading the difference of cycle counter in CPU to calculate the frequency. But I got the CPU frequency is about 1GHz.

Or is there any way in software or registers in hardware can tell me the ARM CPU's frequency?

** Edit **
I asked my colleague to run `perf stat sleep 1` in his real ARMv8 hardware, and we got,

```
 Performance counter stats for 'sleep 1':

              1.89 msec task-clock                #    0.002 CPUs utilized
                 1      context-switches          #    0.530 K/sec
                 0      cpu-migrations            #    0.000 K/sec
                43      page-faults               #    0.023 M/sec
           1859822      cycles                    #    0.985 GHz
            758842      instructions              #    0.41  insn per cycle
             91818      branches                  #   48.632 M/sec
             12077      branch-misses             #   13.15% of all branches

       1.003838600 seconds time elapsed

       0.004158000 seconds user
       0.000000000 seconds sys
```

His ARMv8 is running at 1GHz which matches the output of `perf stat`.
Compared to that in QEMU emulation, the emulated CPU should be also running at 1GHz, am I correct?

Comment: What is in `/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/`

Comment: There is NO such file in my Ubuntu Aarch64

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked up any tools to assist in this?
Cpupower has an ARM release [cpupower 5.19-1](https://archlinuxarm.org/packages/aarch64/cpupower). This should give you the information that you want.
`cpupower monitor` should display current frequency. Depending on what cpu you have, you will need to verify the core cluster type.

As a note, the frequency an ARM cpu has is not always comparable to an x86 cpu frequency. The way that computations are handled are very different.

** Edit

So CPU frequency is measured in Hertz, which is cycles per second. According to your `perf stat sleep 1` the **Emulated** ARM cpu had 36,759,401 cycles in that one second. That would equate to 36.75Mhz, the task-clock result reflects this.

Comment: I updated my question with more info such as `cpupower` in this QEMU emulation, there is NO real useful information about CPU frequency.  Could you be more specific on the way of computing ARM CPU frequency? Thx.

Comment: To clarify if this is not a physical CPU? So you are trying to get the CPU frequency of an emulated CPU?

Comment: That is correct, currently this is an emulation system. Is there a way to get the CPU frequency?

Comment: jmfwolf. I got your point. But with my testing of reading pmccntr_el0, it takes 1,000,444,774 in 1 second (sleep(1)), so which one is right?

Comment: The question comes down to what you are actually trying to measure. The reason  you are  measuring the frequency will help clarify.

Comment: The question could be simplified to 'how to get ARMv8 CPU frequency in runtime?' X86 has TSC register which can help determine CPU's frequency, I want to find something like this in ARMv8.

Comment: Then you should look up the CNTFREQ register in ARM. You will need to either use a real ARM cpu or account for what the emulation does not do. Does QEMU emulate the CPU registers? Take a look at https://embeddedcomputing.com/technology/processing/measuring-code-execution-time-on-arm-cortex-m-mcus

The question that was originally asked is pretty different than where we are at now.

Comment: QEMU does support CNTFREQ, and it is 62.5MHz in my environment. I think it is NOT CPU frequency, it is only a timer in ARMv8 arch. And what I am asking is a way to determine ARMv8 CPU core frequency in runtime, either by reading some registers or by using software to calculate it.  From all the discussion we had, `perf stat sleep 1` can provide the data. And software also can do that, but the software needs to be designed in a right way. I will post my findings as the answer.

Comment: You stated `The question could be simplified to 'how to get ARMv8 CPU frequency in runtime?' X86 has TSC register which can help determine CPU's frequency, I want to find something like this in ARMv8.` 

CNTFREQ is equivalent. Your original question was if you could say it was 1Ghz, the answer is no. But answer your question however you like.

Comment: https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ddi0595/2021-03/AArch64-Registers/CNTFRQ-EL0--Counter-timer-Frequency-register, it says CNTFRQ is `This register is provided so that software can discover the frequency of the system counter.` It is NOT for the CPU frequency. As I said, I want to get the CPU core frequency (nominal frequency) in runtime, so I have to count the CPU cycles, not the 'system counter' cycles.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the question is to get the ARMv8 CPU core frequency (nominal or maximum).  With all the discussion here and my testing in QEMU emulation and real ARMv8 hardware, there are 2 typical ways to get the CPU core frequency.

1. `perf stat sleep 1` can provide reliable data about the CPU frequency (nominal at least).

In QEMU, it shows,

```
t@ubuntu:~$ sudo /usr/lib/linux-tools/4.15.0-189-generic/perf stat sleep 1

 Performance counter stats for 'sleep 1':

         37.075376      task-clock (msec)         #    0.035 CPUs utilized
                 2      context-switches          #    0.054 K/sec
                 0      cpu-migrations            #    0.000 K/sec
                52      page-faults               #    0.001 M/sec
        37,039,955      cycles                    #    0.999 GHz
   <not supported>      instructions
   <not supported>      branches
   <not supported>      branch-misses

       1.055087406 seconds time elapsed
```

Line of 'cycles' shows the emulated CPU is running at 1GHz.

In real ARMv8 hardware (nominal frequency is 1GHz), it shows,

```
:~# perf stat sleep 1

 Performance counter stats for 'sleep 1':

              1.93 msec task-clock                #    0.002 CPUs utilized
                 2      context-switches          #    0.001 M/sec
                 0      cpu-migrations            #    0.000 K/sec
                44      page-faults               #    0.023 M/sec
           1897778      cycles                    #    0.982 GHz
            779587      instructions              #    0.41  insn per cycle
             94295      branches                  #   48.782 M/sec
             12509      branch-misses             #   13.27% of all branches

       1.003847600 seconds time elapsed

       0.000000000 seconds user
       0.004177000 seconds sys
```

The line of `cycles` shows it is running at 1GHz, which matches CPU's nominal frequency.

2. Software can read pmccntr_el0 to calculate the CPU frequency, and the software needs to be designed to stress the CPU to 100% usage, to avoid CPU power management.

Sleep testing result in QEMU emulator is.

```
$ taskset -c 3 ./readpmc
Got pmccntr: 0x35dcdf412, 0x410b77476, diff: 0xb2e98064 (3001647204)
calculated CPU frequency: 1000549068
```

It gets CPU frequency is 1GHz, matches QEMU's emulation.

Sleeping testing result in real hardware (1GHz as nominal frequency).

```
:~/temp# taskset -c 3 ./a.out
Got pmccntr: 0xffffffff8311b937, 0xffffffff8357acf7, diff: 0x45f3c0 (4584384)
calculated CPU frequency: 1528128
```

It shows 1.5MHz, which does NOT matches the nomimal frequency of the real hardware.
By changing the code from sleeping 3 seconds to busy looping 3 seconds, the result shows.

```
:~/temp# taskset -c 3 ./b.out
Inside handler function
Got pmccntr: 0xffffffff8c6857c3, 0x3f39438b, diff: 0xb2d0ebc8 (3000036296)
calculated CPU frequency: 1000012098
```

It shows CPU is running at 1GHz, matching CPU's real nominal hardware frequency.

The conclusion is software can calculate CPU's nominal frequency in ARMv8 as what can be done in X86 (through tsc).